# While working with Google Action Console OAuth, it was rejected for the following reasons

Tags: google-oauth, actions-on-google

While working with Google Action Console OAuth, it was rejected for the following reasons.
please, Help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You appear to be missing the question part of your question.  This appears to be a statement saying that your application was refused and telling you why.

Comment: When do you initiate the account linking in the conversation?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the line, "We couldn't find account creation/linking prompt", I'm guessing your OAuth page didn't have a "Create an account" link.

If you're telling them you want users to use your website to create accounts, users need to be made aware *how* to do that.

If you already have that, add "users can create an account on our OAuth page by clicking [Create an account]" (or however you say it) to your Testing Instructions and resubmit.